# TStDecimal and TurboPower SysTools

Tags: delphi, turbopower

I'm trying to move SysTools to Win64. There is a class TStDecimal which is a fixed-point value with a total of 38 significant digits. The class itself uses a lot of asm code.

Is there someone who already moved this class to Win64? Or is there another class for fixed-point values?

Comment: Can you share some information about the fixed-point value? Eg, how it's defined, a link to the source code, etc? Even if no-one has ported it, someone may be able to convert it based on detailed information in the question.

Comment: SysTools is hosted under Sourceforge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools.

The class TStDecimal  is defined in the unit StDecMth.

It has the following description: 

{Note: StDecMth declares and implements TStDecimal. This is a fixed-
       point value with a total of 38 significant digits of which
       16 are to the right of the decimal point.}